# Freeze plotly-dash graph visualization

Tags: python, plotly, zooming, visualization, plotly-dash

I am working on a dash app, here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import plotly.graph_objs as go

blue = '#6683f3'
orange = '#ff9266'
grey = '#e0e1f5'
black = '#212121'

app = dash.Dash()

app.layout = html.Div([html.Div([dcc.RadioItems(id = 'radio-item',
                                                options = [dict(label = 'squared',
                                                                value = '2'),
                                                           dict(label = 'cubed',
                                                                value = '3')],
                                                value = '2',
                                                labelStyle = {'display': 'block'})]),

                       html.Div(dcc.Graph(id = 'graph',
                                          figure = dict(data = [],
                                                        layout = go.Layout(plot_bgcolor = black)),
                                          style = dict(height = 1000)))])


@app.callback(Output('graph', 'figure'),
              [Input('radio-item', 'value')])
def update_graph(value):

    x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
    y = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
    XX, YY = np.meshgrid(x, y)

    Z1 = XX ** int(value) * YY
    Z2 = XX ** int(value) / YY

    data = [go.Contour(z = Z1,
                       name = f'Z1',
                       zmin = 0,
                       zmax = 100,
                       contours_coloring = 'lines',
                       line_width = 2,
                       showscale = False,
                       showlegend = True,
                       visible = True,
                       colorscale = [[0, orange], [1, orange]],
                       ncontours = 21,
                       contours = dict(showlabels = True,
                                       labelformat = '.0f')),

            go.Contour(z = Z2,
                       name = f'Z2',
                       zmin = 0,
                       zmax = 100,
                       contours_coloring = 'lines',
                       line_width = 2,
                       showscale = False,
                       showlegend = True,
                       visible = True,
                       colorscale = [[0, blue], [1, blue]],
                       ncontours = 21,
                       contours = dict(showlabels = True,
                                       labelformat = '.0f'))]

    layout = go.Layout(plot_bgcolor = black,
                       hovermode = 'x unified')

    figure = go.Figure(data = data, layout = layout)

    figure.update_xaxes(title_text = 'X',
                        linewidth = 1,
                        nticks = 11,
                        gridwidth = 0.5,
                        gridcolor = grey,
                        tickformat = '.0f')

    figure.update_yaxes(title_text = 'Y',
                        linewidth = 1,
                        nticks = 11,
                        gridwidth = 0.5,
                        gridcolor = grey,
                        tickformat = '.0f')

    figure.update_layout(legend = dict(itemsizing = 'constant'))

    return figure


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server()
```

This code produces a graph and a `RadioItems` with two options. The content of the graph is updated accordingly to the `RadioItems` selected option through the `update_graph` function. So far so good.
The problem araises when I zoom/pan the graph and then I change the RadioItems option: the graph is correctly updated but it loses the zoom/pan I made before. Same issue if I show/hide one of the two traces and then I change the RadioItems option: the graph is updated but the visualization option of the traces is resetted.
This behavior is due to the code I have: when a user changes the `RadioItems` option, it is called the function `update_graph` that resets the graph, so properties like pan/zoom or hide/show trace options are lost.
I want to *freeze* these visualization options so that, when a user pans/zooms and then he changes `RadioItems` option, the graph is correctly updates but it keeps the pan/zoom the user made before. The same for the trace hide/show option.
I think there is a way to save in a variable the current displayed area and in another variable the visibility of the traces and recall this variables inside the `update_graph`, but I do not know how to save and recall these properties.

Version info:

```
Python                  3.7.0
dash                    1.12.0
dash-core-components    1.10.0
dash-html-components    1.0.3
dash-renderer           1.4.1
plotly                  4.8.1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is the `uirevision` property (for details, see [the documentation](https://plotly.com/python/reference/#scatter-uirevision)). To keep zoom, pan etc., set this property when you update the figure, i.e.

```
fig['layout']['uirevision'] = 'something'
```

It doesn't matter *what* you set as the value (you can use a number, a string, etc.), it only matters that *the value remains unchanged* during subsequent updates (where you wan't to keep zoom, pan, etc.). Whenever you need to reset the view, change the value to something else, e.g.

```
fig['layout']['uirevision'] = 42
```

Comment: Following your advice, I edited `go.Layout` by adding `uirevision = 'value'` as parameter. This allows me to freeze the graph as I want. But what if I have 2 RadioItems (`'A'` and `'B'`) and I want to freeze the visualization with respect to the first and not with respect to the last?