# Plotly-Dash: How to show the same selected area of a figure between callbacks?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, jupyterdash

Consider a plotly figure where you can select polynomial features for a line fit using JupyterDash:

[image]

If you select an area and then choose another number for polynomial features, the figure goes from this:

[image]

... and back to this again:

[image]

So, how can you set things up so that the figure displays the same area of the figure every time you select another number of features and trigger another callback?

#### Complete code:

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from jupyter_dash import JupyterDash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures 
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline

from IPython.core.debugger import set_trace

# Load Data
df = px.data.tips()
# Build App
app = JupyterDash(__name__)
app.layout = html.Div([
    html.H1("ScikitLearn: Polynomial features"),
    dcc.Graph(id='graph'),
    html.Label([
        "Set number of features",
        dcc.Slider(id='PolyFeat',
    min=1,
    max=6,
    marks={i: '{}'.format(i) for i in range(10)},
    value=1,
) 
    ]),
])

# Define callback to update graph
@app.callback(
    Output('graph', 'figure'),
    [Input("PolyFeat", "value")]
)

def update_figure(nFeatures):
    
    global model

    # data
    df = px.data.tips()
    x=df['total_bill']
    y=df['tip']

    # model
    model = make_pipeline(PolynomialFeatures(nFeatures), LinearRegression())
    model.fit(np.array(x).reshape(-1, 1), y)
    x_reg = x.values
    y_reg = model.predict(x_reg.reshape(-1, 1))
    df['model']=y_reg

    # figure setup and trace for observations
    fig = go.Figure()
    fig.add_traces(go.Scatter(x=df['total_bill'], y=df['tip'], mode='markers', name = 'observations'))

    # trace for polynomial model
    df=df.sort_values(by=['model'])
    fig.add_traces(go.Scatter(x=df['total_bill'], y=df['model'], mode='lines', name = 'model'))
    
    # figure layout adjustments
    fig.update_layout(yaxis=dict(range=[0,12]))
    fig.update_layout(xaxis=dict(range=[0,60]))
    #print(df['model'].tail())
    fig.update_layout(template = 'plotly_dark')
    
    return(fig)

# Run app and display result inline in the notebook
app.enable_dev_tools(dev_tools_hot_reload =True)
app.run_server(mode='inline', port = 8040, dev_tools_ui=True, #debug=True,
              dev_tools_hot_reload =True, threaded=True)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Freeze plotly-dash graph visualization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62267830/freeze-plotly-dash-graph-visualization)

Comment: @emher Close, but not quite. I found the title to be a bit misleading with the `freeze` part. This makes it sound like the figure is unresponsive to all changes. Adding to that, your suggestion is `fig.update_layout(uirevision='some-constant')` which will likely lead readers to belive that it's a placeholder for some *numerical* constant. It turns out that any string will work though, so `fig.update_layout(uirevision='some-constant')` isn't *wrong*. Even `fig.update_layout(uirevision='wrong')` will trigger the same functionality.

Comment: @emher But the primary reason I wrote up this question is that it did not pop up when searching for `[plotly] uirevision`. But I see now that your linked post lacked the `[plotly]` tag. I've fixed that now.

Comment: @emher Your last statement in your answer `Whenever you need to reset the view, change the value to something else.` is not quite correct though, as per my first comment.

Comment: Ah, yes, i see how my phrasing could be misunderstood. I have edited the answer to make it more clear. However, i am not sure that i understand why 'Whenever you need to reset the view, change the value to something else.' is not correct?

Comment: @emher Try changing `'some-constant'` to `'hello-world'`. It seems that uirevevision is set to `constant` as long as there is a random string there. In order to actually reset the viewing behaviour, you'll have to remove `fig.update_layout(uirevision='constant')` all togheter or set `fig.update_layout(uirevision='')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is surprisingly easy and just adds to the power and flexibility of Plotly and Dash.
Just add

```
fig.update_layout(uirevision='constant')
```

to your code and you're good to go:

[image]

For even more control you can set axis properties directly. From the [docs](https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/#layout-uirevision):

> For finer control you can set these sub-attributes directly. For
> example, if your app separately controls the data on the x and y axes
> you might set `xaxis.uirevision=*time*` and `yaxis.uirevision=*cost*`.
> Then if only the y data is changed, you can update
> `yaxis.uirevision=*quantity*` and the y axis range will reset but the
> x axis range will retain any user-driven zoom.

#### Complete code:

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from jupyter_dash import JupyterDash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures 
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline

from IPython.core.debugger import set_trace

# Load Data
df = px.data.tips()
# Build App
app = JupyterDash(__name__)
app.layout = html.Div([
    html.H1("ScikitLearn: Polynomial features"),
    dcc.Graph(id='graph'),
    html.Label([
        "Set number of features",
        dcc.Slider(id='PolyFeat',
    min=1,
    max=6,
    marks={i: '{}'.format(i) for i in range(10)},
    value=1,
) 
    ]),
])

# Define callback to update graph
@app.callback(
    Output('graph', 'figure'),
    [Input("PolyFeat", "value")]
)

def update_figure(nFeatures):
    
    global model

    # data
    df = px.data.tips()
    x=df['total_bill']
    y=df['tip']

    # model
    model = make_pipeline(PolynomialFeatures(nFeatures), LinearRegression())
    model.fit(np.array(x).reshape(-1, 1), y)
    x_reg = x.values
    y_reg = model.predict(x_reg.reshape(-1, 1))
    df['model']=y_reg

    # figure setup and trace for observations
    fig = go.Figure()
    fig.add_traces(go.Scatter(x=df['total_bill'], y=df['tip'], mode='markers', name = 'observations'))

    # trace for polynomial model
    df=df.sort_values(by=['model'])
    fig.add_traces(go.Scatter(x=df['total_bill'], y=df['model'], mode='lines', name = 'model'))
    
    # figure layout adjustments
    fig.update_layout(yaxis=dict(range=[0,12]))
    fig.update_layout(xaxis=dict(range=[0,60]))
    #print(df['model'].tail())
    fig.update_layout(template = 'plotly_dark')
    fig.update_layout(uirevision='constant')
    return(fig)

# Run app and display result inline in the notebook
app.enable_dev_tools(dev_tools_hot_reload =True)
app.run_server(mode='inline', port = 8040, dev_tools_ui=True, #debug=True,
              dev_tools_hot_reload =True, threaded=True)
```